# is.element() and %in% not returning correct value

Tags: r, exists

Below is R script includes logic to determine if element is in list `PPal`

R outputs that `abc` doesn't exist in `PPal`

When I execute

```
> RPal("abc")
```

it returns

```
Error in RPal("abc") : Palette not found.
```

Script:

```
PPal <- list (
  abc = c("#fda726"),
  def = c("#9aa5b4"),
  ghi = c("#bdcad0")
)

RPal <- function(name){

  pal <- NULL

  if (nargs() != 1){
    stop("Enter 1 valid palettes.")
  }

  if (!(is.element(name,PPal))){
    stop("Palette not found.")
  }
  pal <- PPal[[name]]
  pal
}
```

Also tried %in%

```
  if (!(name %in% PPal)){
    stop("Palette not found.")
  }
```

Comment: Where you have `is.element(name,PPal)` you should have `is.element(name,names(PPal))`

Comment: The problem with `%in%` is that you're comparing the list elements to `name`. You could use `name %in% names(PPal)`

Comment: Thank you guys, it now works.